# Plumbing part on shutoff

Tags: plumbing, water, shutoff

[image: plumbing part]

What is the part above the ball valve? What does it do?

Comment: Looks like a pressure regulator.

Comment: As it has a piece prior to the regulator I would bet a check valve and pressure regulator that makes a good system having both.

Comment: Might be a sintered filter rather than a check valve. Also, @JonCuster. put that in the answer box, it is one, and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at, say, [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-3-4-in-Water-Pressure-Reducing-Valve-LF25AUB-Z3/204514212) (no relation, just a handy link) one sees pretty much the exact same thing.

[image]

The data sheet clearly indicates that the lower ‘bump’ is for the inlet strainer, the bell shaped bit above is the pressure regulator.

I have one on the inlet to my house. I live directly down hill from a large city water tank, and the water pressure on a hose bib at the far corner of the house from the supply pipe was over 100 psi, well above the max pressure rating of, well, anything in the house. Adjusting the screw at the right of the picture adjusts the outlet pressure to something more reasonable.

Comment: What boggles me (I've had wells nearly all the time, nearly always have gauges) is that these are frequently installed without the pressure gauges I'd consider pretty much required for sensible operations - minimum one after, better one before **and** one after.

Comment: Depends on the space. Mine is tucked into a wall near the garage where the water comes in - no basement, no real space. A gauge on a hose bib works fine to set and check occasionally…